# How to discriminate between graphs in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, python-imaging-library

I need to discriminate between 2 different graphs in python. Graphs are show below.

```
GRAPH A:
```

[image]

```
GRAPH B:
```

[image]

So, I want to divide these graphs into two categories, A or B. I want to use a property that can be used to discriminate between the two. If the user gives data set for `GRAPH A` or similar to `GRAPH A`, the output should be the graph and its category should be printed. Same goes for the `GRAPH B`.
Following is the code for graph plotting. The category part is missing:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from itertools import count

df = pd.read_excel('graph_nfe.xlsx')

x= []
y= []

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

counter = count(0,1)

def update(i):
    idx = next(counter)
    x.append(df.iloc[idx,0])
    y.append(df.iloc[idx,1])
    plt.cla()
    ax.plot(x,y)

ani=FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=update, interval=100 )

plt.show()
```

We can set a threshold value for if the graphs falls below it, the category is `GRAPH B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you load the full dataset you can do the categorization before your animation starts or you do it when needed. However, it is not clear what you mean by *- or similar to GRAPH A -*. To me it looks like both datasets differ by the length (or the fraction of the full dataset) along which they are at or close to the maximum level.

```
def which_category(df):
    value_threshold = 0.9
    fraction_threshold = 0.6
    cnt = df.iloc[:,1][df.iloc[:,1]>value_threshold].count()
    if cnt / df.iloc[:,1].count() > fraction_threshold:
        return 'GRAPH A'
    else:
        return 'GRAPH B'
```

How do you want the identified category be printed? As a print command is straight forward, I will assume printing it into the plot itself:

```
def update(i):
    idx = next(counter)
    x.append(df.iloc[idx,0])
    y.append(df.iloc[idx,1])
    plt.cla()
    if some_condition:
        plt.text(0.4, 0.4, which_category(df))
    ax.plot(x,y)
```

That way you can implement it that plt.text is only called if the `some_condition` is met.

The category could for example only be displayed once you reach the falling flank of your graph:

```
def update(i):
    value_threshold = 0.9
    idx = next(counter)
    x.append(df.iloc[idx,0])
    y.append(df.iloc[idx,1])
    plt.cla()
    if (df.iloc[idx, 1] - df.iloc[idx-1, 1])  & (df.iloc[idx, 1] < value_threshold) & (idx > 20) < 0:
        plt.text(0.4, 0.4, which_category(df))
        ax.plot(x,y)
```

Where `(df.iloc[idx, 1] - df.iloc[idx-1, 1])` checks for a falling graph, `(df.iloc[idx, 1] < value_threshold)` makes sure that the graph fell beneath the threshold and `(idx > 20) < 0` makes sure that the falling regions at the beginning of your graph are not giving false positives. Especially this last part depends strongly on how other data looks like. You probably have to tweak it.

Comment: By similar to GRAPH A I mean that the graph stays stable for shorter amount of time.

Comment: Can you tell what the some_condition can be?

Comment: Since you are plotting the graphs point by point I thought maybe you only want the category be displayed when your loop reaches the criterion or when the graph is going down again. I updated the answer for the latter.